# Ошибка заполнения RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Из приложения заполняю данные на сервер `Firebase`, и тут же отображаю их в  `RecyclerView`, по при первом запуске когда происходит запись на сервер в  `RecyclerView`  намного больше пунктов чем должно быть, на сервере их нет, они являются клонами друг друга. Вот код:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child(userId).exists()){
                   reference.child(userId).child("KEYS").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                           codes.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class));
                           codesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                           Codes code = dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class);
                           int index = getItemIndex(code);
                           codes.set(index, code);
                           codesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           Codes code = dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class);
                           int index = getItemIndex(code);

                           codes.remove(index);

                           codesAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                       }
                    });
            }else{
                if(newArr.contains("newArr")) {
                    reference.child(userId).child("Тут не пусто").setValue("Да да это правда");
                    for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++) {
                        String cod = "G-" + (k + (k * 3)) * 5553;
                        reference.child(userId).child("KEYS").child(cod).child("cod").setValue(cod);

                    }
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = newArr.edit();
                    editor.putString("newArr","false");
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }

        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос выносом функции получения данных:

```
  reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.child(userId).exists()){
                    reference.child(userId).child("Тут не пусто").setValue("Да да это правда");
                    for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++) {
                        String cod = "G-" + (k + (k * 3)) * 5553;
                        reference.child(userId).child("KEYS").child(cod).child("cod").setValue(cod);


                }
            }

        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
reference.child(userId).child("KEYS").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                           codes.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class));
                           codesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                           Codes code = dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class);
                           int index = getItemIndex(code);
                           codes.set(index, code);
                           codesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           Codes code = dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class);
                           int index = getItemIndex(code);

                           codes.remove(index);

                           codesAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                       }
                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                       }
                    });
```